How to deal with Monad, Functor and Applicative in order to write stateful code
I am attempting to write some stateful code in Haskell. To this end, I follow this material. At this point, I got my way to monads and functors, and, roughly put, I am confused and can't make progress with the material. I have this M(Non)WE:
import Control.Monad

data State s a = State (s -> (a,s))

runState (State f) s = f s

put :: s -> State s ()
put state = State (\oldState -> ((), state))

get :: State s s
get = State (\state -> (state,state))

modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()
modify f = State (\state -> ((), f state))

-- The following 3 rows fail:
instance Functor State where
  fmap f (State s) = State (f x)
  
-- The following 3 rows fail:
instance Applicative State where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad (State s) where
  return x = State (\s -> (x,s))
  
  op >>= f = State h
    where h state0 = let (val,state1) = runState op state0
                         op2 = f val
                     in runState op2 state1
                     
add :: Int -> State Int ()
add i = do old <- get
           put (old+i)
           
main = do
  print(runState (add 1 >> add 3 >> add 5 >> add 6) 0)

The error message is:
question1.hs:16:18: error:
    * Expecting one more argument to `State'
      Expected kind `* -> *', but `State' has kind `* -> * -> *'
    * In the first argument of `Functor', namely `State'
      In the instance declaration for `Functor State'
   |
16 | instance Functor State where
   |                  ^^^^^

question1.hs:19:22: error:
    * Expecting one more argument to `State'
      Expected kind `* -> *', but `State' has kind `* -> * -> *'
    * In the first argument of `Applicative', namely `State'
      In the instance declaration for `Applicative State'
   |
19 | instance Applicative State where
                          ^^^^^

What am I missing here?

instance Functor (State s) where

@willeM_VanOnsem Getting closer. Only one error left.

@coderodde what error? The two you have in your post are the same error, both solved by applying willeM_s suggestion. Please add the error message to the question.

Where did x come from in your definition of fmap?

Again, that's the same error as for the Functor instance and solved in the same way.

State itself is not a functor. For every type s, State s is a different functor. But the same definition applies, because the "structure" of fmap is the same no matter what state type you use; the only thing that is important is how you use f :: a -> b to create a State s b from a State s a value. (Ignoring State wrappers, how do you use f :: a -> b and g :: s -> (a, s) to create a function of type s -> (b, s)?

The same way the Monad instance is defined for State s:
instance Monad (State s) where ...

the Functor and Applicative instances must be defined for State s:
instance Functor (State s) where ...
instance Applicative (State s) where

FYI, the error messages are referring to the fact that the Functor and Applicative constraints apply to types with kind * -> *.  This is the kind for "type functions" that accept a single type argument to give a type, the way that Maybe takes a single type argument, say Int for example, to give a type Maybe Int.    (That's why Maybe can be a valid Functor / Applicative / Monad -- it has the right kind * -> *.)   When you try to make State by itself a Functor or Applicative, the kind is wrong.  The type function State has kind * -> * -> * meaning that it takes two arguments to form a type, like the return type of your add function, State Int ().  On the other hand, State s has the right kind * -> * because it only needs to be applied to one more type (e.g., State s a) to form a type.
Once you've fixed those errors, you'll have another errror because your fmap definition is wrong:
fmap f (State s) = State (f x)

Here, x isn't defined. What you'll need to do is make use of the s variable on the left, which is a function of type s -> (a,s) to construct the right-hand side, similar to how you've defined >>= in the Monad instance.
Spoilers follow...
.
.
.
The following will work, though I've renamed this variable to act, short for a state "action", to avoid confusing it with the state itself:
fmap f (State act) = State (\s -> let (a, s') = act s in (f a, s'))

Alternatively, Functor instances can be automatically derived (and there's always only one correct derivation), so you can just turn on the right extension and add a deriving clause:
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
...
data State s a = State (s -> (a,s))
  deriving (Functor)

and then delete the Functor instance entirely.
The Applicative and Monad instances still need to be defined manually, however.
